# SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access - Incorrect syntax near '<'

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Im trying to migrate this query from Access to a view in SQL Server:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.[2010Q1-Q2 BLABSI Rate by Hospitalstep1]
AS
   SELECT 
      [AcuteHospitals].[HospitalName], 
      [SummaryYQ_LOV].[SummaryYQ], 
      Sum([RateTable_CLABData].[clabcount]) AS [Number of CLABSI], 
      Sum([RateTable_CLABData].[numcldays]) AS [Central Line Days], 
      (CASE 
         WHEN [AcuteHospitals].[LicensedBeds] < '201' THEN 'a'
         ELSE (CASE 
            WHEN [AcuteHospitals].[LicensedBeds] > '500' THEN 'c'
            ELSE 'b'
         END)
      END) AS SizeCat, 
      (CASE 
         WHEN [AcuteHospitals].[LicensedBeds] < '201' THEN '<200 Licensed Beds'
         ELSE (CASE 
            WHEN [AcuteHospitals].[LicensedBeds] > '500' THEN '>500 Licensed Beds'
            ELSE '201-500 Licensed Beds'
         END)
      END) AS BedSize
   FROM 
      ([AcuteHospitals] 
         LEFT JOIN [RateTable_CLABData] 
         ON [AcuteHospitals].[NHSN_ID] = [RateTable_CLABData].[orgID]) 
         LEFT JOIN [SummaryYQ_LOV] 
         ON [RateTable_CLABData].[summaryYQ] = [SummaryYQ_LOV].[StartDate]
   WHERE ((([RateTable_CLABData].[loccdc]) NOT LIKE '%ped%'))
   GROUP BY [AcuteHospitals].[HospitalName], [SummaryYQ_LOV].[SummaryYQ], (
      CASE 
         WHEN [AcuteHospitals].[LicensedBeds] < '201' THEN 'a'
         ELSE (
            CASE 
               WHEN [AcuteHospitals].[LicensedBeds] > '500' THEN 'c'
               ELSE 'b'
            END)
      END), (
      CASE 
         WHEN  < '201' THEN '≤200 Licensed Beds'
         ELSE (
            CASE 
               WHEN  > '500' THEN '>500 Licensed Beds'
               ELSE '201-500 Licensed Beds'
            END)
      END)

GO
```

But I keep getting a syntax error on the '<' and Im not sure why.

there are actually 4 lines like `[AcuteHospitals].[LicensedBeds] < '201' THEN`  but the SSMA doesnt indicate which line the error is on tho Im assuming its the first instance since every line is essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

If `[AcuteHospitals].[LicensedBeds]` is a numeric column, you shouldn't compare it with string values:

Use

```
[AcuteHospitals].[LicensedBeds] < 201
```

instead of

```
[AcuteHospitals].[LicensedBeds] < '201'
```

Access is more forgiving about things like this than SQL Server.

Comment: If LicensedBeds is numeric, SQL will implicitly cast '201' to the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

A few things I see from the snippet you posted.

1) You have two open parenthesis, but only one close.  This could be related to your error.  You actually don't need any parenthesis around a CASE statement.

2) You can simplify your CASE statement to the following.

```
CASE 
    WHEN [AcuteHospitals].[LicensedBeds] < '201' THEN 'a'
    WHEN [AcuteHospitals].[LicensedBeds] > '500' THEN 'c'
    ELSE 'b'
END
```

However, I cannot be certain that this is the cause of your error without seeing the entire query.

**Edit**

The problem is with your `GROUP BY`.  You need a left hand operand for the `<` and `>`

```
  CASE 
     WHEN  < '201' THEN '≤200 Licensed Beds'
     ELSE (
        CASE 
           WHEN  > '500' THEN '>500 Licensed Beds'
           ELSE '201-500 Licensed Beds'
        END)
  END)
```

Comment: I just added the entire query